# ¿Cómo puedo convertir el contenido de 2 celdas en una fila (df) a, digamos, varias celdas más en la misma fila en Python? librería Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucles

Digamos que tengo la siguiente `df` (es una pequeña muestra de uno más grande), cada fila contiene 3 celdas:

```
  Permutations                        FilePermutations
0 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None
1 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png
2 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png
3 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png
4 Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png
.
.
.
```

Todas las celdas de la columna `Permutaciones` permanecen constantes, este `df` de arriba representa algunos [Productos cartesianos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano) que se obtuvieron como resultado de un proceso particular.

¿Cómo podría lograr que se vea como este a continuación?

```
  Fondo            Cuerpo                     Ojos             Color              Pinzas      Puas   
0 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas None
1 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Arena.png
2 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Marron.png
3 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Purpura.png
4 Fondo Oceano.png Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png Ojos Antenas.png Color Amarillo.png Pinzas None Puas Verde.png
.
.
.
```

Comment: Mm... no entendí, cuales son las 3 celdas?

Comment: La del ```index```, la de ```Permutations```, y la de ```FilePermutations``` @Christian

Comment: Una última cosa, todas las filas mantiene el orden `Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas`?? y si no es así, que se debería de colocar en la columna `Fondo` si el elemento no corresponde a tal columna?

Comment: Todas las filas (inclusive en la df más grande) mantienen el orden ```Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas```, las celdas que varían son las de la columna ```FilePermutations``` y obviamente las del ```index```, en total son unas 360 filas de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Utilizando los datos de tu pregunta en un archivo "sample2.csv" cree el siguiente `dataframe`

|  | Permutations | FilePermutations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas | Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None |
| 1 | Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas | Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png |
| 2 | Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas | Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png |
| 3 | Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas | Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png |
| 4 | Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas | Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png |

Puedes utilizar [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) para separar las columnas en listas

```
df['Permutations'] = df['Permutations'].str.split('+')
df['FilePermutations'] = df['FilePermutations'].str.split('+')
```

Esto generaría:

|  | Permutations | FilePermutations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'] | ['Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Antenas.png', 'Amarillo.png', 'None', 'None'] |
| 1 | ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'] | ['Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Antenas.png', 'Amarillo.png', 'None', 'Arena.png'] |
| 2 | ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'] | ['Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Antenas.png', 'Amarillo.png', 'None', 'Marron.png'] |
| 3 | ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'] | ['Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Antenas.png', 'Amarillo.png', 'None', 'Purpura.png'] |
| 4 | ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'] | ['Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Antenas.png', 'Amarillo.png', 'None', 'Verde.png'] |

Luego generar una combinación de elementos entre los elementos en la lista de la columna "Permutations" con "FilePermutations"

```
a = df.apply(lambda x: list(map("{0[0]} {0[1]}".format, zip(x['Permutations'], x['FilePermutations']))), axis=1)
```

Esto devolvería:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['Fondo Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Ojos Antenas.png', 'Color Amarillo.png', 'Pinzas None', 'Puas None'] |
| 1 | ['Fondo Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Ojos Antenas.png', 'Color Amarillo.png', 'Pinzas None', 'Puas Arena.png'] |
| 2 | ['Fondo Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Ojos Antenas.png', 'Color Amarillo.png', 'Pinzas None', 'Puas Marron.png'] |
| 3 | ['Fondo Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Ojos Antenas.png', 'Color Amarillo.png', 'Pinzas None', 'Puas Purpura.png'] |
| 4 | ['Fondo Oceano.png', 'Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png', 'Ojos Antenas.png', 'Color Amarillo.png', 'Pinzas None', 'Puas Verde.png'] |

Luego creamos un nuevo `dataframe` con los nombres de las columnas como describiste en tu pregunta

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a.tolist(), columns=['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'])
```

Y el nuevo `dataframe` queda como lo necesitas (En la respuesta salen los textos de las celdas en dos filas de la tabla porque son un poco largos)

|  | Fondo | Cuerpo | Ojos | Color | Pinzas | Puas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Fondo Oceano.png | Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png | Ojos Antenas.png | Color Amarillo.png | Pinzas None | Puas None |
| 1 | Fondo Oceano.png | Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png | Ojos Antenas.png | Color Amarillo.png | Pinzas None | Puas Arena.png |
| 2 | Fondo Oceano.png | Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png | Ojos Antenas.png | Color Amarillo.png | Pinzas None | Puas Marron.png |
| 3 | Fondo Oceano.png | Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png | Ojos Antenas.png | Color Amarillo.png | Pinzas None | Puas Purpura.png |
| 4 | Fondo Oceano.png | Cuerpo Cuerpo_cangrejo.png | Ojos Antenas.png | Color Amarillo.png | Pinzas None | Puas Verde.png |

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['Permutations'] = df['Permutations'].str.split('+')
df['FilePermutations'] = df['FilePermutations'].str.split('+')
a = df.apply(lambda x: list(map("{0[0]} {0[1]}".format, zip(x['Permutations'], x['FilePermutations']))), axis=1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a.tolist(), columns=['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas'])
```

Comment: Wow, me había olvidado que esta pregunta existía, pero igual, ¡muchas gracias por responderla y solucionarla!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!